# NFS inherit permissions from shared directory - Mac OS client

Tags: linux, mac-osx, ubuntu, nfs, access-control-list

**Short question:** Is there a way to have files on a NFS share on a Mac OS client *inherit* the permissions of the shared directory?

**Scenario:**

- Ubuntu 12.04 server
- Mac 10.7.4 client
- shared directory has 775 permissions
- created files on client have 644 permissions

I tried setting ACLs with the setfacl command, as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/151911/how-to-make-new-file-permission-inherit-from-the-parent-directory), and it appears they are set on the server.

getfacl returns this:

```
# file: Documents/
# owner: someguy
# group: somegroup
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:somegroup:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

However, when I create a new file on the Mac OS client it still has 644 permissions and not the 664 I would expect. Files created on the server have the expected permissions. Files created with another Ubuntu client also have the expected permissions.